# Xcode Multiple UIButton Actions

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uibutton

I have been trying to program a soundboard app, which of course has multiple sounds in it, so far I have two buttons and two sounds, but each button plays the same sound.  I am a noob programmer, so please explain to me in detail what I need to do.  I apologize for my formatting, as this is my first question being asked one stack overflow, everything below is code.  I currently have 2 buttons on my storyboard.  Help would be appreciated.  Below is my ViewController.swift

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button", ofType: "wav")!)
    var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sweg", ofType: "wav")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func soundbutton(sender: UIButton) {
       audioPlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func sound2(sender: UIButton) {
       audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: Deleting the line after view did load just causes my app to crash when the button in tapped, your first solution gave me an error: "Binary Operator '~=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?'"      on the "case" lines.

Comment: check the screenshots

Answer (score 1):

You should use a single IBAction for those buttons ex

```
@IBAction func soundButton (sender: UIButton){
 switch sender.currentTitle! {
   case "sound1"://here you put the title the first button has
      audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
      audioPlayer.play()
   case "sound2"://here you put the title the second button has,here sound2 was an example,because IDK your buttons titles
      audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound2, error: nil)
      audioPlayer.play()
   default : break    
   }
 }
```

currentTitle is the title of the button,so if the first button title is ,you replace sound1 with .

No joke emoji work :)):D

hope that this helps

***Edit***
The wrong thing that you were doing is that you set in the viewDidload `audioPlayer` to sound, and thats why you had just one sound

You can remove that line from viewDidLoad

***Edit: inside the class*** This is what you need inside the ViewController,nothing more,nothing less(),make sure you connect the buttons to the IBAction and disconnect from other methods

```
 import UIKit 
 import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button", ofType: "wav")!)
 var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sweg", ofType: "wav")!)
 var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
 @IBAction func soundButton (sender: UIButton){
 switch sender.currentTitle! {
    case "sound1"://here you put the title the first button has
       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
    case "sound2"://here you put the title the second button has,here    sound2 was an example,because IDK your buttons titles
       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound2, error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
     default : break    
    }
   }
 }
```

the most simple implementation

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
 var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
 @IBAction func soundButton (sender: UIButton){
 if let title = sender.currentTitle{
 switch title {
    case "sound1"://here you put the title the first button has
       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button", ofType: "wav")!), error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
    case "sound2"://here you put the title the second button has,here    sound2 was an example,because IDK your buttons titles
       audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sweg", ofType: "wav")!), error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
     default : break    
    }
   }
 }
}
```

***Now the only error you will have is SIGABART because that buttons have some outlets and actions***

Comment: Deleting the line after view did load just causes my app to crash when the button in tapped, your first solution gave me an error: "Binary Operator '~=" cannot be applied to operands of type 'String' and 'String?'" on the "case" lines.

Comment: What I told you was just one solution.

Comment: Running the app with the suggested code in the iOS Simulator causes it to hang on the launch screen, and displays an error: "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" on the first var sound line.

Comment: with the new code ??your button are named sound1 and sound2.If you just copy paste??

Comment: I get an app crash, which looks like it is caused by my app delegate.  "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {" is marked green with the words "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT"

Comment: How stupid you are , remove all connections from the buttons,and then reconect them to the IBAction.Wait a sec for screenshots if you don't know

Comment: Still doesn't work.  The line mentioned before Appears green with a thread error.

Comment: @spinny747 that means you haven't deleted the action from the button.If you try this a new project,surely it will work

Comment: @spinny747 did you put there the audio file ??

Comment: I did put the audio files.

Answer (score 0):

you need to initialise another AVAudioPlayer with another sound, and play it on second button tap.

Comment: Could you be more specific, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
import UIKit 
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var sound = NSURL(fileURLWithPath:     NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("button", ofType: "wav")!)   
   var sound2 = NSURL(fileURLWithPath: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("sweg", ofType: "wav")!)
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
         }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func soundbutton(sender: UIButton) {
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound, error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
    }

    @IBAction func sound2(sender: UIButton) {
audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOfURL: sound2, error: nil)
       audioPlayer.play()
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you haven't deleted those func(viewDidLoad and func didReceiveMemoryWarning),and why doing  2 IBActions,when you only need one,and if you are using a IBAction just for one button ,why you still have the sender Argument

Comment: yeah it is possible to do with one button..but he says that he is noob programmer..so this is simple and better solution for them.

Comment: I'm thinking that he will want to add more buttons,it will be better to add an another switch case,then a new func,the code will look to blocky.I don't understand  what do you mean "yeah it is possible to do with one button",than I referred  about the IBAction, and if you do thousands of IBAction,why you still have an argument, to make things more complex??

Comment: I used to code provided, but it causes my app to crash whenever a button is pressed.